# Questions about $\mathbb{C}/n\mathbb{C}$

Tags: number-theory, complex-numbers, modular-arithmetic

I have two questions, both questions are quite simple.

1. I'm just curious whether $\mathbb{C}/n\mathbb{C}$ exists? Is it a well defined concept?
2. Is it possible to define $a \equiv b \mod z \quad \text{Im}(z) > 0$ and $a, b \in 
   \mathbb{C}$?

For both it seems to depend on the way one defines modular arithmetic with complex numbers. The most obious way is if $n$ divides $\text{Re}(z_1 - z_2)$ as well as $\text{Im}(z_1 - z_2)$, then $\quad z_1 \equiv z_2 \mod n$. This is no surprise, and so it seems like $\mathbb{C}/n\mathbb{C}$ exists, however I've never seen it come up in mathematical literature anywhere. Is there a reason for this?

For 2. there seem to be multiple ways in which one can define 'modulo a complex number', with different results. It seems to me that for it to be consistent one must define it for Gaussian integers, i.e $a \equiv b \mod(x+iy)$ for $x, y \in \mathbb{Z}$. If this were possible it would be quite interesting to study for example $\mathbb{Z}/z\mathbb{Z}$ for a complex $z$. Does this concept exist? Is there any research done on this? References, explanations, insights, etc are all welcome

---

Thanks to @Stefan for answering 1.

Comment: The Gaussian integers and their quotients are interesting so I would encourage you to keep looking at them. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integer

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Note that the expression $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is not some special notation. It is the quotient of the group (resp. ring) $\mathbb{Z}$ by the subgroup (resp. ideal) $n\mathbb{Z}$, which is by definition the set of all elements of $\mathbb{Z}$ of the form $nk$ with $k\in\mathbb{Z}$.

In that sense, $\mathbb{C}/n\mathbb{C}$ is well-defined. But it is boring because $n\mathbb{C}$ is either $\mathbb{C}$ or $\{0\}$.

A more interesting notion would be something like $\mathbb{C}/(\mathbb{Z}+\mathbb{Z}i)$, but note that the quotient is only taken in the category of groups and not in the category of rings, because $\mathbb{Z}+\mathbb{Z}i$ is not an ideal. In fact, a field does not have any non-trivial ideals.

Comment: Thanks! This answers 1. nicely
Any ideas for 2.?

Comment: @Mako see the section on residue classes in the gaussian integer article I provided earlier. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integer#Congruences_and_residue_classes

Comment: @Mako: Same thing. $\mathbb{C}/z\mathbb{C}$ is trivial because $z\mathbb{C}$ is either $\mathbb{C}$ or $\{0\}$.